# Is it possible to create a form with certain format in backend?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, forms, phoenix-framework

I want to write a simple form and submit to backend. Here is my form:

```
<form action="/users" method="post">
  <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="put">
  <input name="_csrf_token" type="hidden" value="xxx">  
  <label for="user_name">Name</label>  
  <input id="user_1_name" name="user[][name]" type="text" value="Stephen">

  <label for="user_age">Age</label>  
  <input id="user_1_age" name="user[][age]" type="number" value="30">


  <label for="user_name">Name</label>  
  <input id="user_2_name" name="user[][name]" type="text" value="Leo">

  <label for="user_age">Age</label>  
  <input id="user_2_age" name="user[][age]" type="number" value="15">
  <div>
    <button type="submit">Save</button>  
  </div>  
</form>
```

When submitted to backend, the parameters I received are:

```
Parameters: %{"_csrf_token" => "xxx", "_method" => "put", "user" => [%{"name" => "Stephen"}, %{"age" => "30"}, %{"name" => "Leo"}, %{"age" => "15"}]}
```

But I want the parameters to be (one map for each user):

```
Parameters: %{"_csrf_token" => "xxx", "_method" => "put", "user" => [%{"name" => "Stephen", "age" => "30"}, %{"name" => "Leo", "age" => "15"}]}
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Why is this tagged with both Ruby on Rails and Phoenix Framework? Which is it? On Rails / Rack in general you would name the inputs `user[0][name]`, `user[0][age]`, `user[1][name]`. Check out how fields_for works if you want an example.

Comment: @max I am working on phoenix framework, the pure html form makes more sense to  understand the logic. I will transfer to phoenix/rails way after I got answer. What's more, the backend log above is from phoenix/rails

Comment: I wouldn't assume that phoenix and rack actually process form data the same way. They might, but it seems like a bad assumption.

Answer (score 0):

[Phoenix.HTML.Form.input_for/4](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_html/Phoenix.HTML.Form.html#inputs_for/4) is what you need for

```
<%= form_for @changeset, @action, fn f -> %>

 <%= hidden_input f, :_csrf_token, value: "xxx" %>
 <%= hidden_input f, :_method, value: "put" %>

 <%= inputs_for f, :user, fn cf -> %>
   <%= label cf, :name %>
   <%= text_input cf, :name %>
   <%= error_tag cf, :name %>

   <%= label cf, :age %>
   <%= text_input cf, :age %>
   <%= error_tag cf, :age %>
 <% end %>

 <%= inputs_for f, :user, fn cf -> %>
   <%= label cf, :name %>
   <%= text_input cf, :name %>
   <%= error_tag cf, :name %>

   <%= label cf, :age %>
   <%= text_input cf, :age %>
   <%= error_tag cf, :age %>
 <% end %>

 <div><%= submit "Save" %></div>
<% end %>
```